# Get java annotations for fields in derived classes

Tags: java, android, annotations

In my Android application, i have the following classes:

```
public abstract class A implements IA {
    private void findAnnotations() {
        Field[] fields = getClass().getFields();

        // Get all fields of the object annotated for serialization
        if (fields != null && fields.length > 0) {
            for (Field f : fields) {
                Annotation[] a = f.getAnnotations();

                if (annotation != null) {
                    // Do something
                }
            }
        }

        return serializationInfoList
                .toArray(new SoapSerializationFieldInfo[serializationInfoList
                        .size()]);
    }
}
```

and

```
public abstract class B extends A {
    @MyAnnotation(Name="fieldDelaredInB")
    public long fieldDelaredInB;
}
```

When i call `B.findAnnotations()`, i can see that `getClass().getFields()` returns the fields declared in B - `fieldDelaredInB`, e.g., but no annotations for these fields are returned - i.e, i get null when i call `f.getAnnotations()`, `f.getDeclaredAnnotations()` or whatsoever.

Is this an issue of a superclass unfamiliar with attributes of derived classes? seems weird, considering the fact that the fields of the derived class DO appear when i call `getFields()` from the superclass.

Any ideas of what am i missing?

Thanks,
Harel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An annotation is not loaded at runtime unless it is marked for runtime retention with `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)`.  You must place this `@Retention` annotation on your `@MyAnnotation` annotation:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead

```
if (annotation != null) {
    // Do something
}
```

you should have

```
if (a != null) {
    //do something
}
```

Also, it would be faster if you'd search the annotation you need, like this:

```
Annotation a = f.getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
```